# Apache 2.2.4 Proxy Balancer Extremely Slow When a Balancemember is down

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I am using apache 2.2.4 as a reverse proxy server in my DMZ. The Proxy Balancer appears to work great when the two BalancerMember servers are up. But if I shut one down, It takes roughly 30-45 seconds to get anything to load on my site every time I load a page. Here is my configuration:

```
ServerName mywebsite.com
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny, allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://10.10.10.10:80/outside loadfactor=1 retry=60
BalancerMember http://10.10.10.11:80/outside loadfactor=1 retry=60
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /outside balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse /outside balancer://mycluster/

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !

<Location /balancer-manager>
SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>
```

The server acts as a reverse proxy for REST services that sit behind it. When I load the web application, it calls the 
REST services multiple times, so I don't know if that could also be causing the slowness, as the Proxy is getting hit with many requests at once.

Comment: Some info in logs?

Comment: It isn't putting anything in the logs.

Comment: Try remove retry setting

Comment: I removed retry, it is still behaving the same.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `ProxyTimeout` to just a few seconds - what's happening is that it's sitting there trying connections to the down backend for a long while, not timing out.

Setting something like `ProxyTimeout 3` will cause the connection to fail more quickly, then your `retry=60` setting will cause the down server to not be used again for the next minute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apache is not restarting after using that attribute. Is that available in Apache 2.2.4? If it is, I tried using the following forms: ProxyTimeout 3 and ProxyTimeout=3

Comment: @JavaScript_Guru Yup: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout Where did you put the directive?

Comment: Here: BalancerMember 'http://10.10.10.10:80/outside loadfactor=1 retry=60 ProxyTimeout=3'

Comment: @JavaScript_Guru Ahh, ok: It either needs to be on its own line after `</Proxy>`, and note that the syntax is `ProxyTimeout 3` and not `ProxyTimeout=3` - or, alternatively, you can have it on your `BalancerMember` lines by setting `timeout=3`.

Comment: Ok. I added it underneath like you said. However, it doesn't seem to make a difference in timing. To give some more info: When my webpage loads, it calls on the services behind the proxy server several times. Could that be contributing to the problem?

Comment: @JavaScript_Guru That.. shouldn't make a difference?  What do the individual requests' timings look like in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: The whole app takes about 4 seconds to load uncached, and the services requested average about 110ms.

Comment: If I shut down one of the servers and then look at the load balancer admin page, it still reports both servers as "OK." It's like it never recognizes that the server is down.

Comment: I mean, what's it look like when one of the servers is down - where's the time being spent (ie, 3 seconds for each of hundreds of resources, or a really long time on any given resource).  For the balancer admin page, does it still show OK even immediately after a request fails?

Comment: Ah. No, everything hangs or times out after 30-45 seconds. Nothing loads from those servers that whole time.

Comment: @JavaScript_Guru Hmm, what do the server's access logs look like for those requests - what response code do they get sent?  And the balancer manager shows them as up the whole time, right?

Comment: Yes, the balance manager shows them as as up the entire time. As for the codes, they are getting code 200 with each response even while one of the servers is down. I did find this in the error log:(OS 10060) A conneciton attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because host has failed to respond. : proxy: HTTP: attemp to connect to 10.10.10.11:80 failed

Comment: @JavaScript_Guru Well, I'm a little stumped that it's taking so long to flip over to the other server, and not marking them as down properly.. try adding `connectiontimeout=1` to the `BalancerMember` lines?  If that doesn't work, let's try a packet capture to see what the heck is going on, are you familiar with `tcpdump`?

Comment: connectiontimeout=1 breaks apache. It won't restart while that attribute is in there. As for tcpdump, it's a windows environment, and I don't have permission to install software on the server. On another note, it seems to me that it never actually recognizes that the server is down. Also, it's supposed to split the incomming requests 50/50 because the loadfactor is set to 1 on each member. So shouldn't at least half of my requests work right away? Or shouldn't it work half the time?

Comment: @JavaScript_Guru Yeah, something's funky... maybe add `%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e` to your log format to see where it's sending the requests?  And try throwing `status=+E` on one of the `BalancerMember` lines to see if that puts it into error state in the manager properly?